# Cant able to set value using useState hook? Why this happens?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [userDetail, setUserDetail] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    getUsersData()
}, [])

const getUsersData = async () => {
    const userResp = await MyService.getInstance().getEntities()

    let data = []
    console.log(userResp)

    if (userResp) {
        userResp.map((d) => {
            data.push({
                name: d.name,
                username: d.username
            })
        })
        
        setUserDetail(data) // < --------this line--------
        console.log(data)
    }

    console.log(userDetail)
}
```

setUserDetail doesnt set the value for userDetail Array even console.log(userDetail) shows empty array.
like this:

[image: Console shows this o/p]

Comment: `setUserDetail` doesn't mean any assignment to `userDetail` until the next time `useState` is invoked; `console.log(userDetail)` is *before* that.

Comment: Reading `state` right after calling `setState()` is a potential pitfall.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok so how should i get rid of that because i was doing this mistake everytime ?

Comment: Only `console.log(userDetail)` immediately after `useState`, when it's got the new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. You are using the .map method as .forEach. The purpose of the .map method is to return a new array transformed. Then, this data array is not necessary.If you want to transform an array, you can use a map, but is not necessary to create a new array. Map will return the new array transformed.

```
  const[ userDetail , setUserDetail ] = useState([])

  useEffect( () => {
    getUsersData()
  }, [])

  const getUsersData = async() =>{
    const userResp = await MyService.getInstance().getEntities()
    console.log(userResp)
    if(userResp){
     setUserDetail(
     userResp.map((d) => (
        {
          name:d.name,
          username:d.username
        })
     ))
    }
  }

 console.log(userDetail)
```

2. Try to move your console.log outside the method getUsersData. Then you will see all values for userDetail after each render.